# EAccessviolation AV Error using variables in Private

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm tidying up some code I've been given, for some reason, if the variables are defined under 'Private' (where they need to be to constrain access within this unit). I get EAccessViolation error when writing to them. If I loosely define them under Var just before implementaion they can be accessed ok. I'm comparing my structure with other similar units, where the Private units work fine & cant spot any significant differences.. Any suggestions?

Error MSG: Project --- raised exception class EAccessViolation Error with message 'access vilation error in module----. Read of address 0000050F

```
interface
uses
  dialogs, math, dateutils, SysUtils, classes;
type
     //double = extended;   
     TDoubleDoubleArray = array of array of double;
     TSunPositionAlgorithm = class (TObject)
         private
           FLocationChanged: boolean;
         public
           Constructor Create;
           Destructor Destroy;
           procedure SetDefaults;
         end;
  Var
    SunPositionAlgorithm : TSunPositionAlgorithm;
           F_L0: Double;
           F_L1: TDoubleDoubleArray;

implementation
  {TSunPositionAlgorithm }

constructor TSunPositionAlgorithm.Create;
begin
  SetDefaults;
end;

procedure TSunPositionAlgorithm.SetDefaults;
Begin
F_L0:= 1;                   // works ok
  FLocationChanged:=true;  // throws eaccess violation error
End;
```

Calling function (added to Post after David H's 1st question):

```
  procedure TSun.NRELPositionOfSun(const DateTime: TDateTime; var Azimuth, Elevation, Declination: double);
  Var

    LSunPositionAlgorithm : TSunPositionAlgorithm;
  Begin
    LSunPositionAlgorithm := TSunPositionAlgorithm.Create;
    Try
      LSunPositionAlgorithm.SetDefaults;

  blah..


    Finally
      LSunPositionAlgorithm.Destroy;
    End;
  End;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown the code that calls this code. However, it's pretty obvious that you don't have a valid `TSunPositionAlgorithm` object.

Get one of those like this:

```
procedure Test;
var
  spa: TSunPositionAlgorithm;
begin
  spa := TSunPositionAlgorithm.Create;
  try
    spa.SetDefaults;
  finally
    spa.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You probably have code like this:

```
procedure Test;
var
  spa: TSunPositionAlgorithm;
begin
  spa.SetDefaults;//oops, spa has not been initialised yet  
end;
```

or possibly like this:

```
procedure Test;
var
  spa: TSunPositionAlgorithm;
begin
  spa.Create;//oops, spa has not been initialised yet  
end;
```

**Update** You've now shown the calling code but you clearly haven't shown it all, because the code in the question does not exhibit the behaviour you describe. The point I make remains, you must have an invalid object reference somewhere. I've shown a couple of the most common ways for that to come about. But there are other ways to get an invalid object reference.

---

The other thing wrong with the code in the question is your destructor. They must always be marked with the `override` directive.

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

You have to do this in order for your destructor to be called when an object is freed.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick response, good point about checking the calling code, though my structure was pretty much same as your test fn, (I've added the calling function to the original question). ALso good point about create/destroy syntax, I'll tidy that up & see if it runs

Comment: hmm, no cigar as yet, problem occurs with&without fulldebug mode & mem leak reporting in fastmm4

Comment: The code in the question isn't the real code. That code does not produce an access violation. Please post real code that exhibits the behaviour you describe.

Comment: ah..lightbulb moment... the full code would be massive, but I set up a tiny test program..which worked ok (like the exert above)..So looking back at the main code & the create/destroy structure, I think the problem could be that the TSunPositionAlgorithm is created by another object which is also created at runtime (but not correctly). And therefore I need to check all the create-call-destroy structure at different levels of the hierarchy is correct.

Comment: The only explanation for that error is that the object reference is invalid. I just offered up two very common ways for that to come about.

Comment: found the bug :-) I had called 'SunPositionAlgorithm.SetDefaults' somehwere else outside the create-destroy, removed that call & all is now working well :-). Thanks to David for the tips :-)